# How do I use a javascript function to automatically update a series of table rows after taking in an input from a database via laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I'm hoping that someone can outline a plan of attack for a problem I have.

I have a table that I've created, and for each row, it queries the database and returns a duration (with other things, but the duration is important for this question).

For example, a row will have:

- The Name of an 'Event'
- How Long the 'Event' goes for (Duration) in Minutes.

What I'm trying to do is create two columns (*Start Time* and *End Time*). The first row will take it's start time from the initial event start time, and calculate the end time by adding the duration to the initial start time.

```
First Row (Start Time) = Initial_Event_Start_Time
First Row (Finish Time) = Initial_Event_Start_Time + Duration
```

For each row after, it'll take the previous row's Finish Time, save that as it's own Start Time, and add the row's duration to that start time to create it's Finish Time.

```
For all other rows {
    Row (Start Time) = Previous Row's Finish Time
    Row (End Time) = Row (Start Time) + Duration
}
```

So the final output would be:

```
 Start Time | End Time | Duration | ---- | ---- | ---- |
```

Where the 'Start Time' and 'End Time' columns are generated using a JS Function on the fly and appended to the rest of the table.

The reason why I want this to happen on the client-side is the table can be sorted (using JQuery's Sortable Library) and every time a row is moved to another position, I want the JS function to fire off and calculate all the new times for the newly sorted table.

The initial Event_Start_Time is stored in the database when a new 'event' is created.

I'm using Laravel and MySQL as the stack to do this.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, let me know.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could have your controller return the data and then in your javascript do something like this:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
"ajaxSource": "<route-to-controller-function-that-returns-data>",
  "columnDefs": [ {
    "targets": 4,
    "data": "description",
    "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
        logic to create time stamps in JS
    }
  } ]
} );
```

This is kind of a stab, but maybe a helpful start.

Comment: So, I'd be taking the Ajax Source directly from the controller that returns the data to the table and select for the specific data rows and iterate through it?

Comment: Yes you shouldn&#39;t even have to iterate it will handle that.